# LOAD DATA INFILE throws unexplained exception

Tags: mysql, windows, csv, mysql-workbench, load-data-infile

After running:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/myusername/Downloads/Medicare_Physician_and_Other_Supplier_PUF_aa_CY2012.csv'
INTO TABLE medicarepuff
ENCLOSED BY '"'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

As shown here:

[image]

I get the following result:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Here's a preview of the CSV:

```
+------------+------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------+----------------------------------+------------------+------------+------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+
|    npi     | nppes_provider_last_org_name | nppes_provider_first_name | nppes_provider_mi | nppes_credentials | nppes_provider_gender | nppes_entity_code | nppes_provider_street1 | nppes_provider_street2 | nppes_provider_city | nppes_provider_zip | nppes_provider_state | nppes_provider_country | provider_type | medicare_participation_indicator | place_of_service | hcpcs_code |      hcpcs_description       |  line_srvc_cnt  |  bene_unique_cnt  |  bene_day_srvc_cnt  | average_Medicare_allowed_amt | stdev_Medicare_allowed_amt | average_submitted_chrg_amt | stdev_submitted_chrg_amt | average_Medicare_payment_amt | stdev_Medicare_payment_amt |
+------------+------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------+----------------------------------+------------------+------------+------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+
| 1003002494 | ANDERSON                     | JOSEPH                    | M                 | M.D.              | M                     | I                 | 802 B ST               |                        | SAN RAFAEL          |          949013026 | CA                   | US                     | Pathology     | Y                                | O                | 88305      | Tissue exam by pathologist   | 1,797           |               165 |                 168 | 133.43                       | 20.95                      | 263.23                     | 41.17                    | 105.53                       | 25.87                      |
| 1003002494 | ANDERSON                     | JOSEPH                    | M                 | M.D.              | M                     | I                 | 802 B ST               |                        | SAN RAFAEL          |          949013026 | CA                   | US                     | Pathology     | Y                                | O                | 88342      | Immunohistochemistry         | 568             |                72 |                  73 | 131.74                       | 16.22                      | 255.64                     | 31.27                    | 102.43                       | 39.47                      |
| 1003002494 | ANDERSON                     | JOSEPH                    | M                 | M.D.              | M                     | I                 | 802 B ST               |                        | SAN RAFAEL          |          949013026 | CA                   | US                     | Pathology     | Y                                | O                | G0416      | Sat biopsy prostate 1-20 spc | 25              |                25 |                  25 | 866.27                       | 0                          | 1733                       | 0                        | 693.02                       | 0                          |
+------------+------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------+----------------------------------+------------------+------------+------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Here's a text preview of the file:
[image]

Comment: That looks very much like a bug. Please file a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: did you try specifying your column names not just table name for the load data infile?